# $parse Syntax Error when binding Angular Expression to Directive Attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

### Can't bind attributes on template using directive

I can't seem to bind attributes on the templates using directives. Any help or suggestion would be great!

It is giving me this error:

> [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the
> expression [{{$ctrl.CalendarOpen}}] starting at
> [{$ctrl.CalendarOpen}}].

Here is my directive:

```js
app.directive('datePickerDirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
          
        },
        template: `
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="shortDate"
                   name="date" is-open="{{$ctrl.CalendarOpen}}"
                   ng-model="test" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                   ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />`,
        controller: function() {
            var $ctrl = this;
            $ctrl.CalendarOpen = true
        },
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Remove the double curly `{{` brackets from the `is-open` attribute, i.e. `is-open="$ctrlCalendarOpen"`.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks! it doesn't show in the html that is-open="true" so strange but it is working. If I add an id="{{$ctrl.CalendarOpen}}", it would not give me that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the double curly `{{` brackets from the `is-open` attribute:

```
template: `
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           uib-datepicker-popup="shortDate"
           ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶=̶"̶d̶a̶t̶e̶"̶ ̶i̶s̶-̶o̶p̶e̶n̶=̶"̶{̶{̶$̶c̶t̶r̶l̶.̶C̶a̶l̶e̶n̶d̶a̶r̶O̶p̶e̶n̶}̶}̶"̶
           name="date" is-open="$ctrl.CalendarOpen"
           ng-model="test" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
           ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />`,
```

The `uib-datepicker-popup` directive is attempting to evaluate the `is-open` attribute using the [$parse Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) and [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) that start with `{{` are illegal.

From the Docs:

> ### Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error
>
> #### Description
>
> Occurs when there is a syntax error in an expression. These errors are thrown while compiling the expression. The error message contains a more precise description of the error, including the location (column) in the expression where the error occurred.
>
> To resolve, learn more about [AngularJS expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), identify the error and fix the expression's syntax.
>
> [— AngularJS Error Reference - $parse:syntax Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax)

---

> If I add an `id="{{$ctrl.CalendarOpen}}"`, it would not give me that error

In that case there is no error because there is no directive parsing the `id` attribute. The expression inside the double curley `{{` bracket is being evaluated by the [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) Service, converted to text, and inserted into the DOM.

When a directives parses an attribute as [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), it is not wise to mix interpolation into that expression.

From the Docs:

> #### Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
> - Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)